# Flutter project unable to resolving AndroidX reference

Tags: android, flutter, androidx

Making a flutter app and working on the android specific part.
When I try to use the JobIntentService in my Kotlin class, I get an “Unresolved reference” for “androidx.core”.

Tried to add the dependencies in the build.gradle file and update both kotlin and gradle but nothing works.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration

Comment: Already tried that. Doesnt work. When I alt+Enter on the class, it doesnt even show the androidX import option, just the android.support one

Comment: Okay, I don't know why but they changed the documentation. I'll share my solution for androidx problems.

Comment: Sure, looking forward to it

Answer (score 0):

First, we need to add these two lines to `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

In `android.app` directory `build.gradle` file, change these two lines:

```
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

into:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
```

and change SDK's for smoother compatiblity if you are okay with it:

```
compileSdkVersion 28 => compileSdkVersion 29

minSdkVersion 16 => minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 28 => targetSdkVersion 29
```

In `android` directory `build.gradle` file, change these two lines:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

into:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.41"
    }
```

You can try gradle `3.3.1` or `3.3.0` versions also.
Note that, we changed kotlin gradle plugin version as hardcoded, instead you can change:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
```

This is my personal solution, you may encounter some problems but as far as I see, it works perfect.

Comment: @AbdelghaniBekka did you change everything i pointed out at above?

Comment: yes. every single thing. Used more recent version of each plugin/dependencies though

Comment: don't use latest versions, use the versions I showed, also try without changing kotlin_version. if you are still getting error, please share the log if possible.

Comment: Sure. I’ll use those versions right away and tell you

Comment: @AbdelghaniBekka Don't forget you may need `flutter clean` and try gradle version `3.3.1` and `3.3.0` also.

Comment: what's a playground version?

Comment: Done. still nothing though

Comment: Just to be sure, I tried on my other PC where android studio was never installed and it makes the same problem

Comment: @AbdelghaniBekka in fact, you don't need Android Studio but in that case you need to install Android SDK manually.

Comment: Yes, I understand.

Comment: So, no idea on how to fix it?